# select all text in a textarea with CTRL+A

Tags: c#, winforms

In a winforms application, is it possible to select all text using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just write the KeyDown event handler for the text box:

```
    private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
        if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.A)) {
            textBox1.SelectAll();
            e.Handled = e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
        }
    }
```

---

UPDATE: starting with .NET 4.6.1, TextBox now has this shortcut keystroke pre-defined.

Comment: Select the text box.  In the Properties window click the lightning-bolt icon.  Double-click KeyDown

Comment: tried, and ran it but am not able to get the select-all, copy action working using CTRL A followed by CTRL + C

Answer (score 2):

Note that Ctrl-A to select-all works out-of-the-box (by default) in the RichTextBox control.

Answer (score 1):

put event onkeypress and use SelectAll Method

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.selectall%28v=vs.95%29.aspx